# Using RewriteRule only for a specific subfolder/project

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, .htaccess, apache2

I have an application in a subfolder "subfolder" of Apache so I can use a URL such as: `https://example.com/subfolder/#/v2/login` instead of `https://example.com/#/v2/login`.

I have the following in the `.htaccess` file in my htdocs folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(?!subfolder/).* subfolder/$0 [L,NC]
```

The problem is that it's doing the rewrite even for the root URL of my server; for example, if I go to `https://example.com/`, I see the home page of my application in "subfolder". I would like this rewrite rules to apply only to the application in "subfolder".

I also tried putting the `.htaccess` file inside "subfolder", but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(?!subfolder/).* subfolder/$0 [L,NC]
> ```

To exclude just the root URL (in `.htaccess`) you can change the `RewriteRule` pattern to match 1 or more (`.+`) characters, instead of 0 or more (`.*`) that you have currently:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!subfolder/).+ subfolder/$0 [L,NC]
```

Alternatively, to exclude all files that exist in the root of the site (or anywhere for that matter), include two additional conditions:

```
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!subfolder/).+ $0 [L,NC]
```